# uploading csv file to trigger firestore collection update

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, antd

I'm trying to make a feature in admin panel (with React and Antd framework).

I currently have around **15000 ~ 20000** user info in a csv file. This csv file is regularly updated. Since I have a pretty huge list I was thinking of creating an upload feature where admin can upload the regularly updated csv file so it is transformed into JSON and only selected fields are stored to firestore. This means everytime I upload a new file, all 15000~20000 (26mb) data records are overwritten. **Is it inefficient to create this kind of workflow?** There's a chance that these data becomes larger so I can't possibly update them manually.

Can someone give me some advice on how to handle such situation.

Comment: How do you select which columns are to be stored? Will the name of columns change? Do individual rows change often or is it mainly new rows at the end of the file? Does this CSV file have IDs that are used for the documents in the collection?

Comment: My initial thoughts are to upload to Cloud Storage, which triggers a Cloud Function that parses the data into JSON and then uploads information about the parsed data to Cloud Firestore. If the data becomes too large for one Cloud Function to handle, the first Cloud Storage function splits the uploaded file into smaller chunks (~2000-3000 lines) and uploads them back to Cloud Storage to be processed by another Cloud Storage function that parses them into the database.

Comment: The name of the column should be fixed and individual rows do get updated  regularly (montly basis) but mainly new data records are added. The csv file do have a unique ID. I'll try with the method you provided but I should go over the whole doc in firestore right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers allow from 2 to 4 (some even larger) (GB) maximum size of file to upload so your file is not large.
And I used to work with task like this before and can say that `antd` table does it easy. Only filters work a little slowly.

##### Here is an example I did

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


const columns = [
   /** Here was my columns */
]

const App = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    const handleUpload = (e) => {
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = event => {
            try {
                const result = event.target.result;
                setData(JSON.parse(result));
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
        }
        reader.readAsText(file);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <input type="file" onChange={handleUpload}/>
            <Table
                columns={columns}
                dataSource={data}
            />
        </>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Glad if my answer was helpful to you :) Regards!